# Determine state of MOSFEt transistor

Tags: mosfet, circuit-analysis

> Consider the circuit below:
>
> [image]
>
> It is known that:
>
> \$V_{to}=2V\$, \$V_{DD}=5V\$, \$R_{D1}=1,0k\Omega\$, \$R_{D2}=0,6k\Omega\$.
>
> \$K=0,4\frac{mA}{V}\$ for both transistors.
>
> Determine the state of both transistors.

I have difficulty with this problem, because I don't know where to start.

Do any of you have some tips about how to start on a problem like this? And if so, what would you do for this problem?

Comment: It's normal practice to use dots where wires join and, if 4 wires join, use two dots to avoid uncertainty.

Comment: Oh I didn't draw this circuit. It's a picture from an exam question.

Comment: That doesn't exempt you from posting circuits on this site that are unambiguous. You must take responsibility for what you post.

Comment: I wasn't aware of that.

Comment: if you assume there is a dot between Q1 and RD1 then the transistor is diode connected. Then Q1 and Q2 will act as a current mirror and have the same current.

Comment: Hmm, where does that get me though?

Comment: It gets you to understanding the circuit better and then posting a schema that is unambiguous.

Comment: Is it less ambiguous now?